# Is the sentence formatting I do here view logic or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page containing a partial view with a list and a partial view with three filter options. If the list is empty, I show a special partial view instead of the list with some tips for the user. The tip will instruct the user to widen the filter options that are not already set to it's most generic form. I could just present a bulleted list of all the options the user could change, doing something like this (LocalizedText is generated from a resource file):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Models" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<EmptyResultViewModel>" %>
<div class="warning">
<ul>
   <% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedCustomerNumber)) %>
   <% { %>
       <li><%: LocalizedText.TipCustomerNumber %> </li>
   <% } %>
   <% if (Model.SelectedPeriodOption != PeriodOption.EntirePeriod) %>
   <% { %>
    <li><%: LocalizedText.TipPeriod %> </li>
   <% } %>
   <% if (Model.SelectedFilterOption != FilterOption.None) %>
   <% { %>
    <li><%: LocalizedText.TipFilter %> </li>
   <% } %>
</ul>
</div>
```

I think this would be considered OK view logic. However, I want it to be one grammatically correct sentence. I now have four extra tip resources:"

```
Tip0 = "No results found";
Tip1 = "No results found, consider choosing {0}.";
Tip2 = "No results found, consider choosing {0} or {1}.";
Tip3 = "No results found, consider choosing {0}, {1} or {2}.";
TipCustomerNumber = "another customer number";
TipPeriod = "a different period";
TipFilter = "a more generic filter";
```

And my view becomes this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Models" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<EmptyResultViewModel>" %>
<% var tips = new List<string>();
   // Add the tips of the filter items that are not set to the most general search criteria to a list.
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedCustomerNumber))
   {
       tips.Add(LocalizedText.TipCustomerNumber);
   }
   if (Model.SelectedPeriodOption != PeriodOption.EntirePeriod)
   {
       tips.Add(LocalizedText.TipPeriod);
   }
   if (Model.SelectedFilterOption != FilterOption.None)
   {
       tips.Add(LocalizedText.TipFilter);
   }
   // Depending on how many tips there are, choose the correct tip format.
   string message;
   switch (tips.Count)
   {
       case 0:
           message = LocalizedText.Tip0;
           break;
       case 1:
           message = string.Format(LocalizedText.Tip1, tips[0]);
           break;
       case 2:
           message = string.Format(LocalizedText.Tip2, tips[0], tips[1]);
           break;
       case 3:
           message = string.Format(LocalizedText.Tip3, tips[0], tips[1], tips[2]);
           break;
       default:
           message = LocalizedText.Tip0;
           break;
   } %>
<div class="warning">
    <%: message %>
</div>
```

Now I see so much code in my view compared to only a tiny bit of html. This made me worry about whether I'm putting too much logic in my view. However, in a sense all the logic is around formatting the message.

I just wanted to check whether I'm doing this in the right way or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stops you from passing a pair, `[Model, Message]` as an actual model to view? Or even create extra wrapper class to pass message together with model. Consider:

```
class ModelWithMessage
{
    public object Model { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

as your view model.

This way you can do all the formatting logic in controller and view can remain as simple as it gets.

My point being, **all** the logic you do in your view currently is view-independant - it rings a bell it should not be there.

**Edit in regards to discussion in comments:**

Before putting any logic in view, it's good to ask yourself a question: can this be done in my controller/model? Often the answer is yes. Having properly designed model/controller will result in very simple and lighweight views, purely for content display, which is what view should do - *accepts necessary information from the controller and renders a user interface to display that* ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)).

Minimalistic view will benefit you later, for example when you realize you need to display same content in other places aswell, perhaps using new view. In your original approach, you'll have to copy logic from the old view into the new view. Copying stuff from one file to another might not sound like a big deal, but let's remember about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. What if you have 15 views? Do you want to have same formatting logic in all of them? What if your manager comes and tells you formatting has changed? Do you want to update 15 view files, or 1 controller...?

When approaching such problems, it's worth to take a minute and answer yourself questions like those.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that sentence formatting would be a view thing. Should I send only the message to the view, or should I send the list of tips to the view?

Comment: @Matthijs: edited to show example - message is enough, as it is message what you want to display (together with actual model of course).

Comment: @jimmy: I think in my case the message _is_ the model. The view will be nothing more than `<div class="warning"> <%: Model %> </div>`. In the first case I described, would you also say that I put too much logic in the view or not?

Comment: @Matthijs: you're correct, the message is actual model. As for first case - there's logic there aswell, and it can be safely moved to controller. You want to display list of tips - provide your view with list, don't build it using view. Simple IEnumerable<string> would be enough to just iterate over and generate <li> tags.

Comment: @jimmy: Could I also reason that my view displays a list of strings(tips). Either in a li list or in a grammatically correct string? Then using that reasoning, I would leave the switch statement in my view and just pass it an IEnumerable<string> as a model. The view then decides between an unordered list or a gramatically correct sentence. Or am I again moving too much logic into the view?

Comment: @Matthijs: before putting any code other than displaying values in view, ask yourself a question: can I do this in controller without too much trouble instead? In your both cases, answer is yes. View shouldn't "ask" any questions - it gets data and renders it. There shouldn't be any "do I display this as a list, or single string?". This is what controller is for. Generally, good approach is to have very lightweight view and put all logic you can in model/controller (whether it's business logic or display logic).

Comment: @Jimmy: sorry for being hard headed, but I want to get this right. To clear up something, I didn't mean that my view would have an if statement which determines: list or sentence. I meant that the controller just wants a list of tips displayed and the view renders that in whatever way it wants. I feel that if the sentence formatting (in this case the switch) is in the controller then I would also have to move things like: `if(Model.NrOfResults == 1) { <%: "1 result found" %> } else { <%: string.Format("{0} results found", Model.NrOfResults) %> }` to the controller. But that doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Matthijs: no problem. My opinion remains the same; example you posted *can* be moved to controller. Whether it should or not, depends only on you. Same problems remain true, however. How will you deal with changing requirements? How will you do unit testing? It's much easier with logic in controller.

Comment: One more thing: I'm not saying **all** logic should be gone from view. Of course, in some cases it's perfectly justified to have logic in views, eg. to decide whether you should display <p> or <div>, or whether link should be present or not. The kind of view-logic, determining what markup to use and such - it's view's job. But content formatting, picking different messages etc (as it's in your case) - it's the kind of stuff you want to prepare in controller.